# ApplicationBarIconButton not displaying

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I create images from online at picresize.com to use as application bar icons.  I made them 48 x 48.  The only thing I didn't do was make the background transparent.  Now the icons just show as white blocks and nothing else.   This page, [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431806(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431806%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), specifies what should be done but doesn't say a must.  Any thoughts or experiences in this happening to others?

```
appBarButton =
                new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/<my_button>.png", UriKind.Relative));
            appBarButton.Text = "<text>";
            appBarButton.Click += appBarButton_Click;

            ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(appBarButton);
```

Comment: The code for the applying of the application bar icon was just added.  The spot for the image shows but the image doesn't display.

Comment: Does your file name really have < > in it?

Comment: Also have you tried not overloading the constructor and just setting the IconUri after its initialized?

Comment: Are you creating the app bar in XAML then editing it in the backend code?

Comment: <> are not in the actual code, I just put those in as placeholders as the actual names are kind of irrelevant.  I create the ApplicationBar via the .cs file.  I took an image from a tutorial i went through and that one works completely fine so that is why I am thinking it has to be something with the images I created as the other one shows up completely fine.

Comment: Please show the code for the app bar creation and also link to your image

Answer (score 1):

The transparent background is a must.

Instead of using that picresize.com web service, you should probably learn to use Photoshop, Paint.Net, or any other descent image editor that works on your computer not on someone else's computer.

Comment: I was kind of thinking and leaning towards that is what it had to be.  The images work fine when linked to just the source on a normal Image control.  It is in the ApplicationBar is where they do not display.